# How to add posts to homepage cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, posts

I'm new to cakephp. So I want to ask you, how to add posts to homepage.
I created posts by this tutorial http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial

What should I do next?

I tried to google it, but nothing works.

Thanks.

home.ctp

```
<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: you are probably missing `$uses = array('Post');`, if you are getting `"Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object`.  Can you paste the contents of your PostsController?

Comment: If he's following Cake naming conventions, then he won't need `$uses`. Please check that your model is named `Post.php`, your controller is named `PostsController.php`, and having `App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');` and `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redirect your homepage to the `index()` of `PostsController`.

Go to your `routes.php` file and change this line:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

for this one:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

(assuming that your `index()` actually contain a list of all your posts)

`Router::connect` will catch when an user attempt to go to the url on the first parameter, and will redirect it to the action in the controller on the second parameter

Comment: I tried this, but then i get an error "Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\Controller\PostsController.php 
Line: 7"

Comment: That's a problem from your controller method (probably `index()`), not from the redirect. Anyways, can you post your code where this error is thrown? So we can help you

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Thanks, it works, but if i want to display posts and for example recipes in home page, what should i do then?

Comment: You can import any model you want on a controller with `$uses` variable, or on the fly with `$this->loadModel('Recipe');`. Then you can do a find as usual over this model